# 9oldandroids - view still clickable after translationX/Y (even with visibility GONE) - Android < 3.0

Tags: android, nineoldandroids

I use 9oldandroids for animation in my app.
in Android devices >= 3.0, everything works fine.

In Android < 3.0 devices, I have an annoying problem:
I have a view with a few buttons.
Say I translated that view's y position from its location (viewY) to somewhere outside the screen (viewY + screenHeight).
Even though the view is no longer visible, its buttons are still clickable at their ORIGINAL location.

I tried setEnabled(false), setClickable(false), setFocusable(false) and a lot more failing ideas.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Might want to change the title if you can. It looks like you "heart" android

Comment: Now that this is issue is resolved, any ideas? :)

Comment: I don't sorry. I'll try to dig around though.